# Displaying conditional amount of fields in UI (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface

I am using layout xml documents for my ui controls.

I need to create and remove these controls (input fields) on the fly, based on how many results I get back from my database.

For each group, there can be 0..* fields and these are prepopulated from the database.

Also, it would be good if I can invoke a method to create an additional field; something like the address book, where you can click + or - to add or remove a phone or other detail.

In a "psuedo" style, I'm guessing something like this:

1. Check database - How many of X are there [y]?
2. Create Y fields.

The user may then add new fields, so once I click submit i need to apply all of that to database.

Any examples or hints greatly welcomed.  Hope this make sense! :)

Comment: You didn't really ask any questions here. What have you tried and where specifically are you encountering problems?

Comment: I have been using xml to generate UI's, but the fields shown in these cases are static.

To try and be more concise I am trying to:

- Specify a screen in a generic way, so that I may have 0 or many input fields, depending on the number of rows returned by my database query.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this in code, XML is more for interfaces that don't have changing numbers of fields, unless your adding items to a view like a ListView. Then you just have to use

```
view.addView(child);
```

You may, or may not, want to create a custom list adapter for your database. You can find some great tutorials by searching Custom list adapters in google.

Comment: Could I place an input field and label within a listview?

I am trying to make something that is very similar to the edit contact screen on Android address book.